# Deconvolution of 2 vectors (1 know + 1 unknown)

Tags: r, matlab, curve-fitting, deconvolution

I am currently trying to deconvolute 2 vectors (a & b) from 1 (c). Actually, I have access to the recorded data of (a) & (c) but not (b). All are signal vs time with signal totally random. I convert everything in histogram and I'd like to extract only the distribution of (b) for my work. Of course I can not only recorded it.
Do you know a reliable approach to "remove" the data from (a) to the data from (c)?
So far, I tried to simply subtract the frequency of (a) to (c) but a part of the distribution of (b) is still missing and I don't know how to rebuilt the missing part.
If you have any idea, please let me know. Cheers!

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. But if you are looking for a method, then that's not really a programming question. You might get better help at [stats.se] instead.

Comment: Look for Wiener filter.